# Template debugger not outputting information about add-ons

Tags: templates, debugging

I have Template Debugging and Output Profiler turned on for my site, but i'm not seeing any debug information about my add-ons being used on the site.

On any other site it would show what's happening with things like CE Image, CE Tweet etc.

I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem before? i've checked the logs but i think it's something on the server or something with EE in general that is simply preventing certain tags being processed.

Would be greatful for any assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: You're logged into the CP when trying to view the front end, correct? And not logged in on www on one and without on the other or anything like that? Not using a config file where template debugging etc are set to 'n'?

Comment: Correct. It is showing me the template debugger.It's just not showing me anything related to parsing tags from addons. :/

Comment: Weird. Are there any add-ons that you specifically have to enable debugging in your config for?